# C++/Cli circular inclusion

Tags: .net, c++-cli, circular-reference

Hi everybody I have two classes that both need the other one included, I have tried to include in A.h file the class B header and in B.h file the class A header but I was getting errors due to the circular include, after some research I have found the solution that's called forward declaration but for me is not working, that's my actual situation:

```
// Game.h

#ifndef _GAME_H_
#define _GAME_H_

#ifndef _GRAPHICSDEVICE_H_
#include "GraphicsDevice.h"
#endif

using namespace BSGameFramework::Graphics;

namespace BSGameFramework
{
    public ref class Game
    {
        public:

            Game();
            virtual ~Game();

            property GraphicsDevice^ Device
            {
                GraphicsDevice^ get()
                {
                    return device_;
                }
            }

// Other code here

        private:

            GraphicsDevice^ device_;
    }
}

#endif
```

And this is the GraphicsDevice class:

```
// GraphicsDevice.h

#ifndef _GRAPHICSDEVICE_H_
#define _GRAPHICSDEVICE_H_

// forward declaration
ref class Game; // <-- this is giving me error C2872: 'Game' : ambiguous symbol

using namespace BSGameFramework;

namespace BSGameFramework
{
    namespace Graphics
    {
        public ref class GraphicsDevice
        {
            public:

                GraphicsDevice(); // I need to pass my Game class to the constructor
                virtual ~GraphicsDevice();

// Here other code

         }    
     }
}
```

Can somebody help me please? I'm becoming crazy xD

**SOLVED**

I've solved replacing ref class Game; with namespace BSGameFramework { ref class Game; }

Comment: What do you mean by forward declaration "is not working?"  Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: There's another identifier named "Game" somewhere else in your code.  We can't see it.

Comment: Please read to the end, I've put comments on the code!

Comment: @HansPassant no, there isn't, if I delete ref class Game; it will work all fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I've solved replacing ref class Game; with namespace BSGameFramework { ref class Game; }